# Telegram WebHook query string

Tags: php, telegram

I wonder if there is a possibility to pass GET query string to a telegram bot backend using Webhook.

For example, when i share a link to my bot, e.g. t.me/mybot?param=value

Is there any way i can access a param=>value pair when receive webhook requests from Telegram on my backend whe the user enters a channel or type any commands?

P.S. looking for conceptual answers not an actual code. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [Deep linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @newsha yes. thanks. i just couldnt find what its called like :P